# How to tell if a day is passed using java

Tags: java, calendar

I have a string with name of days in it , i just want to see that in that string of days , which is the upcoming day.
For example the string contains "Sun,Mon,Tue,Fri,Sat"
and if today is Wednesday it should return fri only.
Anyone got an idea how to do this?
At the moment i am doing this thing but it seems to return sun too although sunday is already past.

```
        static String[] strDays = new String[] { "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu",
        "Fri", "Sat" };

    String nexday="sun,mon,tue,fri,sat";     
    String nexdayone[] = nexday.split(",");
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar futurecal = Calendar.getInstance();
    for (int i = 0; i < nexdayone.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            if (strDays[j].equalsIgnoreCase(nexdayone[i])) {

                futurecal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, j);
                if (futurecal.after(now)) {
                    Log.d(now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)+" --after-- "+j,""+strDays[j]);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Today is Wednesday, and the upcoming day is Friday?? Is that so, because your String does not contain _Wed,Thu_ ?

Comment: @jlordo That is correct, because Thursday is not in the given string

Comment: yes , i want to check which is the upcoming day out of the days present in string.

Comment: And the day after Sat is Sun?

Comment: well i am assuming that sunday is passed already in this week or it isnt? i have tried using 
       cal.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.SUNDAY); but the result are inconsistent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution that uses SortedSet to find the next day.

```
private static SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("E");

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // Put the days in the list into a sorted set
    TreeSet<Integer> daySet = new TreeSet<Integer>();
    for (String day : "Sun,Mon,Tue,Fri,Sat".split(",")) {
        daySet.add(dayOfWeek(day));
    }

    // Find the next day in the list, starting from today
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int today = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, findNext(daySet, today));
    System.out.println(fmt.format(cal.getTime()));
}

/**
 * Parses a day name, and returns the number of the day in the week.
 */
private static int dayOfWeek(String day) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(fmt.parse(day, new ParsePosition(0)));
    return cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
}

/**
 * Finds a value in the sorted set that is greater than 'from'.
 * If there are no greater values, return the first value.
 */
private static int findNext(SortedSet<Integer> set, int from) {
    SortedSet<Integer> tail = set.tailSet(Integer.valueOf(from));
    return tail.isEmpty() ? set.first() : tail.first();
}
```

Suppose it was Tuesday today. I wasn't sure whether to return Tuesday or Friday. The solution above would print "Tue". If you need "Fri", i.e. the next day that isn't today, you can use:

`Integer.valueOf(from + 1)` in `findNext`.

Comment: Just a point to note if you use this solution: SimpleDateFormat isn't thread-safe. If you intend to call the code from multiple threads concurrently, you shouldn't store the SimpleDateFormat in a static variable. The easiest way to fix it is just to create a new instance each time you use it.

Answer (score 3):

So you want to find the next weekday starting from today that ist listet in your string?

I would do a hash describing a week and always pointing to a hash-value of "false"

```
Sun->false
Mon->false
Tue->false
Wed->false
Thu->false
Fri->false
Sat->false
```

No, exploding your string, you could set all occurences in that string to true in the hash. For your example this would be

```
Sun->true
Mon->true
Tue->true
Wed->false
Thu->false
Fri->true
Sat->true
```

now you can start at the current weekday (calendar) and walk the hash until you get a hash-value of "true". The key delivering true will be your weekday you looked for!

Comment: I was about to give an answer using string-operations, because I couldn't avoid them with this problem. But this is a really great method... have to remember it by the time!

Comment: If you used a hash, you'd have to be careful not to lose the order. So probably a LinkedHashMap. And the walk function would have to deal with going back to the start of the hash, if you reached the end.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/). Its a great library for java date/time calculations.

To parse `String` to `Date` in Java use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) (`parse` method).

Answer (score -1):

```
Try this.

 public static void main(String a[]){
 String days [] = {"Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"};
    Date d = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat  st = new SimpleDateFormat ("EEEEE");
    String day = st.format(d);
    for(int i=0;i<days.length;i++){
        if(days[i].equals(day)){
            System.out.println(days[i+2]);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is just returning the next-but-one day. It's not taking into account the set of days specified in the question.